# Aggregate selected rows as total and group by datetime in sql query

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql

I have a complex query which provides output as below.

```
Name Date       Value1 Value2
D    1493803432  12    14
S    1493803432  20    22
T    1493803432  24    42
D    1493803424  20    15
S    1493803424  30    23
T    1493803424  65    42
D    1493804556  22    11
S    1493804556  45    23
T    1493804556  55    24
```

My desired output is to add row to this as sum of two or more rows.
 and group by date field, sample as below.

```
Name Date    Value1   Value2
D    1493803432  12    14
S    1493803432  20    22
T    1493803432  24    42
TS   1493803432  44    64
D    1493803424  20    15
S    1493803424  30    23
T    1493803424  65    42
TS   1493803424  95    65
D    1493804556  22    11
S    1493804556  45    23
T    1493804556  55    24
TS   1493804556  100   57
```

I am able to do union but not able to group by the date for the same. So TS is sum of T&S excluding D and for the individual date field.

Comment: you are correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could try this:

```
SELECT NAME, DATE, VALUE1, VALUE2 
FROM <your complex query>
UNION ALL
SELECT 'TS' AS NAME, DATE, SUM(VALUE1) AS VALUE1, SUM(VALUE2) AS VALUE2
FROM <your complex query> 
WHERE NAME IN ('T','S')
GROUP BY DATE
ORDER BY DATE, NAME
```

Comment: I tried on rextester and it works...Are you sure you inserted <your complex query> correctly?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a query like the following:

```
SELECT Name, Date, Value1, Value2, 1 AS grp
FROM mytable

UNION ALL

SELECT 'TS' AS Name, Date, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN Name IN ('T', 'S') THEN Value1 ELSE 0 END) AS Value1,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Name IN ('T', 'S') THEN Value2 ELSE 0 END) AS Value2,
       2 AS grp
FROM mytable
GROUP BY Date, grp
ORDER BY Date, grp
```

The query uses *conditional aggregation* in order to sum *only* `'T'`, `'S'` records in each group. Field `grp` is a number literal used by the `ORDER BY` clause in order to achieve the desired output.

[**Demo here**](http://rextester.com/MUIA30571)

Comment: I am excited to see the demo, but it throws error. "Error occurred"

Comment: @D14 the demo works,  I  don't know about your actual  data/query.

Answer (score 0):

Try as

```
SELECT name,
       date_col,
       TO_NUMBER (value1),
       TO_NUMBER (value2)
  FROM my_table2
UNION
  SELECT 'TS' name,
         (date_col),
         SUM (CASE WHEN name IN ('T', 'S') THEN value1 ELSE '0' END) value1,
         SUM (CASE WHEN name IN ('T', 'S') THEN value2 ELSE '0' END) value2
    FROM my_table2
GROUP BY date_col
ORDER BY date_col, name
```